# Implementing a custom Data Structure to replace 2 hashmaps

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

I'm using two ConcurrentHashMaps to store the following data.  I'll use the following as an example

```
private Map<Player, FootballTeam> playerTeamMapping;
private Map<FootballTeam, League> teamLeagueMapping;
```

Given just the `FootballTeam` object, I need to be able to retrieve either the `Player` or `League` objects and perform some operations

Cases to consider:

- If there are no `Player`'s associated to a `FootballTeam` but a
  `FootballTeam` entry exists then remove the `FootballTeam` entry from
  `teamLeagueMapping`.
- If a `Player`(s) changes their `FootballTeam` but a `FootballTeam`
  entry exists then remove the `FootballTeam` entry from
  `teamLeagueMapping` only if no other Player is referencing the
  `FootballTeam`

So far i'm using both maps defined above but for learning purposes, i've been told I will need to define my own data structure to solve this problem.

I'm thinking of creating of creating a generic class `ThreeWayHashMap<Left, Middle, Right>` that is backed by the 2 maps `(Left = Player, Middle = FootballTeam, Right = League)`.  Is this the best approach to take? I need to basically keep three maps in sync when deleting so when removing entries (i'll need to make sure I perform these operations on both).

Comment: Why you want to create a generic class? Is this a generic problem for your use case? Otherwise you can also wrap these concept inside your own class. Generic implementation will be unreadable and you will not be able to change it is future easily.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I would if I could but this is a learning exercise on implementing the problem without a database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your existing classes to represent the mapping.
`League` should have `Set<FootballTeam>` and `FootballTeam` should have `Set<Player>` and both League and FootballTeam should have utility methods to add or remove a player from the team and add or remove a team from league.

```
public class League {
    Set<FootballTeam> teams = new HashSet<FootballTeam>();

    public void addPlayer(FootballTeam team, Player player) {
        team.addPlayer(player);
        teams.add(team);
    }

    public void removePlayer(FootballTeam team, Player player) {
        team.removePlayer(player);
        teams.remove(team);
    }

    public void movePlayer(FootballTeam from, FootballTeam to, Player player) {
        from.movePlayerTo(to, player);
        if (from.getPlayers().size() == 0 ) {
            teams.remove(from);
        }
        teams.add(to);
    }
}

public class FootballTeam {
    private Set<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();

    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
       player.setTeam(this);
       players.add(player);
    }

    public void removePlayer(Player player) {
       player.setTeam(null);
       players.remove(player);
    }

    public void movePlayerTo(FootballTeam to, Player p) {
       player.setTeam(to);
       players.remove(p);
    }
}
```